# Is there a way to find included Specflow scopes at a BeforeTestRun level?

Tags: nunit, specflow

I'm working with multiple features and scenarios and am looking for a way to find out what scopes are included in a test run at the time to test run start, if that's possible.

There's a large-ish subset (category) of our tests that require a setup that takes 5-10 seconds--currently we're using a BeforeFeature to optimize this setup as much as we can but we have several features (but not all) under the same scope. We'd like to run this setup only when that category of tests of tests is included in the test run.

in pseudo code it would essentially be

```
[BeforeTestRun]
If test run includes scenarios/features with tag "AdvancedSetup"
AdvancedSetup();
```

Answer (score 0):

In SpecFlow this information is not available.
But perhaps your test runner has this information available.

FYI: Tags are translated to TestCategories.

Comment: Hmm maybe. On second thought it was actually easier to just have our advanced setup be a singleton

Answer (score 0):

NUnit allows use of a higher-level setup that applies to a namespace. You access this by creating a `SetUpFixture`. If SpecFlow gives you a way to map features into specific namespaces, you could use this.